# Файловый поток не сохраняется

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var file in AttachmentFile)
               {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FileName,file.FileName);
               }
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

На выходе получаю пустой архив. Что делаю не так?

Примечательно то, что у архива есть размер, но файлов в нем нет.

Comment: Может быть, вы забыли перемотать stream к началу?

Comment: `AttachmentFile` точно не пустой?

Comment: @kmv да, аттачмент содержит 3 файла, там все норм

Comment: @VladD я думал при создании файла стрим с начала начинается.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев очень странно, в остальном ваш код рабочий.

Comment: @kmv наверное стоило указать, что тип у него IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ? Хотя, поштучно файлы сохраняются, не получается только архив

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев: Это да, но после окончания записи поток находится в конце файла, и если вы потом снова читаете из этого потока, то видите ноль байт.

Comment: @VladD я слышал, что в такой конструкции метод flush сам вызывается, и файл на диске все равно должен создаться

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев: Да, с `using` данные попадают корректно в файл. Но если вы повторно используете `stream`, не перемотав его на начало, должны быть проблемы. Если вы открываете новый `stream` (или просто смотрите в файл), проблемы где-то ещё.

Comment: @VladD уже нашли проблему) В ответе ниже

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев: Ага, вижу. Очень хорошо, что нашли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С учетом вашего [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540054/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment683260_540054) о `HttpPostedFileBase`. Свойство `FileName` указывает имя переданного файла *на клиенте*, на сервере файла по такому пути не существует. Его содержимое можно получить через свойство `InputStream`:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) {
        foreach (var file in AttachmentFile) {
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open()) {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Во, то что нужно! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var file in AttachmentFile)
               {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FileName,file.FileName);
               }
               archive.Save(somepath);
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: У объекта ZipArchive нет метода Save

Answer (score 0):

Переписал ваш код. Все отрабатывает, файлы заархивированы и видны при открытии архива.

```
const string path = @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\testzip.zip";

string[] attachmentFiles =
{
    @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\poker.txt",
    @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\yep.txt",
    @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\test.txt"
};

try
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (ZipArchive arch = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var file in attachmentFiles)
            {
                arch.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
        }
     }

     Console.WriteLine("SUCCESSFULL!!!");
     Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Забыл в вопрос написать, что файлы я от клиента получаю, и пути у них нет. Так бы конечно решил другими способами